# How to select rows in which column two and three are not equal to each other and to 0 or 1?(with awk)

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file like this:

```
AX-75448119 0 1
AX-75448118 0.45 0.487179
AX-75474642 0 0
AX-75474643 0.25 0.820513
AX-75448113 1 0
AX-75474641 1 1
```

and I want to select the rows that column 2 and 3 are not equal each other and 0 or 1 (both of them)! (i.e if column 2 and 3 are similar but equal to 0.5 (or any other number except 0 and 1) I would like to have that row)
so the output would be:

```
AX-75448119 0 1
AX-75448118 0.45 0.487179
AX-75474643 0.25 0.820513
AX-75448113 1 0
```

I know how to write the command to select the rows that column 2 and 3 are equal to each other and are equal to 0 or 1 which is this:

```
awk '$2=$3==1 || $2=$3==0' test.txt | wc -l
```

but I want exactly the opposite, to select every rows that are not the output of the above command! 
Thanks, I hope I was able to explain what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might work for you if I get your requirements correctly.

```
awk ' $2 != $3 { print; next } $2 == $3 && $2 != 0 && $2 != 1 { print }' INPUTFILE
```

See it in action at [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/vSYPu)

Comment: Can be simplified to `awk '$2 != $3 || ($2 == $3 && $2 != 0 && $2 != 1)' filename`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:(?)

```
awk '($2==0 || $2==1) && ($3==0 || $3==1) && $2==$3{next}1' file
```